# Typescript default getter of class properties

Tags: typescript, generics, getter

Suppose I have a class with internal private properties:

```
export class foo {
    private bar_:string;
    private baz_:number;
    constructor() { }
```

I know that I can get the values from bar and baz by writing a getter for the variable.

```
    get bar():string {
        return this.bar_;
    }
    get baz():number {
        return this.baz_;
    }
```

This then allows me to access data using:

```
let A:foo = new foo();
console.log(foo.baz);
```

Is there a way to have a simple generic getter, so when working with a more structured class, I could access any field without needing to write an individual get.

```
console.log(A.field2);
```

The field2 is not a defined getter, but I would like to be able to do something like the following in the class:

```
export class foo {
    private bar_:string;
    private baz_:number;
    private field2_:string;
    constructor() { }

    get X():any {        // X here is some placeholder that could be used, which contains the field name being asked (bar_, baz_, etc.)
        return this.X;       // This would assume that a field is the same name as what was passed.
    }
```

On the HTML or other area, I could access the value as `A.bar_` which would allow me to protect the private variable, but get external access to it without the need to write a getter for each field.  This could then be extended to more complex structures as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the properties to be read only and you can just set them in the constructor, you could use the `readonly` modifier:

```
export class foo {
    constructor(
        public readonly bar:string,
        public readonly baz:number,
        public readonly field2:string) { 

    }
}
```

If you only want to access the property from HTML templates, you could use a decorator to create getters, but they will not be present on the type:

```
function createGetter (target: any, key: string) {
    let propName = key.substr(0, key.length - 1);
    Object.defineProperty(target, propName, {
        get: function() {
            return this[key]
        }
    });
}


export class foo {
    @createGetter private bar_:string;
    @createGetter private baz_:number = 10;
    @createGetter private field2_:string;
    constructor() { }
}
```

If you don't mind a bit of convoluted syntax and just declaring the properties, you coulda access the from typescript as well:

```
function withGetters<TProps>() {
    return <TBase>(cls: new () => TBase) : new () => TProps & TBase => {
        return <any>cls;
    };
}
class baseFoo {
    @createGetter private bar_:string;
    @createGetter private baz_:number = 10;
    @createGetter private field2_:string;
    constructor()  { }
}
export const foo = withGetters<{ 
    readonly bar: string;
    readonly baz: number; 
    readonly field2: string; 
}>()(baseFoo);
```

Comment: Impressive.  But why `let propName = key.substr(0, key.length - 1);`?

Comment: @jcairney that was just the convention used in the question, the fields end in `_` and the properties have the `_` removed. Took me a while to remember, this was a while back :)